# np.loadtxt vs np.genfromtxt

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, genfromtxt

when I use the following np.loadtxt code to load the data of the format:

```
2017-07-26,153.3500,153.9300,153.0600,153.5000,153.5000,12778195.00
```

the data gets loaded just fine, loadtxt code->

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = np.loadtxt("goog.csv",
                                  dtype={'names': ("b'Date", 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adjusted_close', 'Volume'),
                                        'formats': ('U10', np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float)},                               
                                  delimiter=',',
                                  skiprows=1,
                                  unpack=True)
print(a)
```

Output->

```
['2017-07-26' '2017-07-25' '2017-07-24' ..., '2000-01-05' '2000-01-04'
'2000-01-03']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

BUT upon using the corresponding np.genfromtxt code gives the ValueError: too many values to unpack, I used the following genfromtxt code->

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = np.genfromtxt('goog.csv',  
                                    dtype={'names': ("b'Date", 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adjusted_close', 'Volume'),
                                           'formats': ('U10', np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float)},
                                    delimiter=',',
                                    skip_header=1,
                                    unpack=True)
print(a)
```

Output->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/sonika jha/PycharmProjects/csvCheck/csvCheck.py", line 84, in <module>
download_stock_data()
File "C:/Users/sonika jha/PycharmProjects/csvCheck/csvCheck.py", line 66, in download_stock_data
unpack=True)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My final goal was to load the date in string datatype and the rest in float using genfromtxt.

Comment: What is the output in both cases? What is the error?

Comment: @sophros made the edit please review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` handle unpacking from structured data differently

`loadtxt` docs:

> unpack : bool, optional
>
> If True, the returned array is transposed, so that arguments may be
>       unpacked using `x, y, z = loadtxt(...)`.  When used with a structured
>       data-type, arrays are returned for each field.  Default is False.

`genfromtxt` docs:

> unpack : bool, optional
>
> If True, the returned array is transposed, so that arguments may be
>       unpacked using `x, y, z = loadtxt(...)`

The `loadtxt` in this last quote is a typo.

If I replicate your sample line 3 times, and run `genfromtxt` (with `unpack=False`):

I get a (3,) array with the defined `dtype`:

```
In [327]: data
Out[327]: 
array([('2017-07-26', 153.35, 153.93, 153.06, 153.5, 153.5, 12778195.),
       ('2017-07-26', 153.35, 153.93, 153.06, 153.5, 153.5, 12778195.),
       ('2017-07-26', 153.35, 153.93, 153.06, 153.5, 153.5, 12778195.)],
      dtype=[('bDate', '<U10'), ('Open', '<f8'), ('High', '<f8'), ('Low', '<f8'), ('Close', '<f8'), ('Adjusted_close', '<f8'), ('Volume', '<f8')])
```

`loadtxt` produces the same thing

But `loadtxt` with `unpack` ends up doing

```
a = data['bDate`]
b = data['Open']
etc.
```

that is, assigning one field to each of the variables.

But `genfromtxt` does

```
a = data[0]
b = data[1]
etc
```

That is, one row or element of the 1d array to each variable.  With many more elements than your 7 variables, it complains about to too many values to unpack.

So either stick with `loadtxt`, or don't use `unpack` with `genfromtxt`.

I think loading the structured array, without `unpack` gives you more options when doing further processing.